# How To Create A Live BackUp and Do An In Place Restore

Tags: boot, server, backup, restore

I need to be able to remotely run a live backup of an Ubuntu server, which is on a VPS without physical access and then also be able to recover to that backup in place.

I do not have console access, and I have no control over the network, so no PXE booting. The VPS does not offer backups without expensive support contracts. I also cannot change the partition scheme. I have a single LVM that stores `/boot`, `/root`, and all else.

I have evaluated a few dozen solutions, all of which presented their own problems. Not having an extra partition or device complicates most of the options out there, additionally so without network booting. It seems to be easy-ish to take a live snapshot with Relax and Recover, or possibly DD of my partition, but recovering to that partition in place with no access to the machine and no PXE is a hurdle.

I'm lost on how to proceed. Every solution I found seems to assume I have something I don't have. What few threads that come close to addressing this are not encouraging:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212757/is-possible-to-remote-mount-an-image-that-can-boot-and-install-itself

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you create backup using tar, it will be enough to copy all your files, however the problem will arise when you try to extract that archive into a live system. Some binaries or libraries may not update because they will be in use by the system, and you will end up in a mess.

You should get some support from your hosting provider (for the new VPS). Usually they have some features for that case, for instance my hosting provider allows me to switch my VPS to "repair mode", in that mode new VPS is created with basic Linux software, and my VPS's disk is mounted there, allowing me to change it however I want and then leave repair mode. Or maybe you can just send your tar archive to the support team, asking them to extract it to your VPS when it's offline.